# How to prevent a custom repository method from being deleted when regenerating a jHipster entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I have used the jhipster entity generator to create an entity called UserInformation. I then created a custom repository, say `findOneByUserId()`, in the `UserInformationRepository.java` class and I am able to successfully use it.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface UserInformationRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInformation, Long> {

    Optional<UserInformation> findOneByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

However, whenever I perform an update on the entity via: `yo jhipster:entity UserInformation` the entity classes are regenerated and my custom repository method is deleted. 
Is there any way of preventing custom repositories from being removed when an entity is regenerated?

I haven't been able to find an answer to this online :(

Many, many thanks for your opinion and time!
Cheers!

Comment: I rely mostly on git branching and merging with this strategy: `git merge -s recursive -Xours ...` see https://gist.github.com/gmarziou/6cc0788f8e7cb21a61a7b14f32b9a657

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

Every time I'm doing any kind of generation with JHipster on an existing project, I push everything on git to be sure to have a backup. After that, I make sure to take a good look a diffs when resolving conflicts in the interactive tool in JHipster. That way, you can choose to not overwrite you repository. It's a bit tedious but at the end, it works.

You can also check that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WVpwIUEty0) that explains how to efficiently work with JHipster without risking overwriting custom code.